# Handling text files with Python

Tags: python

It seems that there are broadly two ways of how to initiate text handling in Python.

- Option1: use the **open, close / with** functions (inbuilt functions in Python).
- Option2: use the **pandas** library.

I'm more friendly with pandas and currently not getting the needs of using option1.
My question is: *What benefits do we have in using option1 over option2?*

Thankyou.

Comment: Why would you use pandas for plain text?

Comment: ```pandas``` is used to analyze data. data read by pandas is usually in table format (csv). ```open, close / with``` is used to read raw data from files (text, csv...)

Comment: Are you talking about `open()` as in the standard builtin function to open files? That's a function that allows you to open any file and read its contents, either as bytes or text - what in `pandas` does that? Sure, `pandas` allows you to open files and interpret their contents (it may even use `open()` for that), but it's a way more specialised (and oversized) tool than a basic `open()` which is more than sufficient for most cases.

Comment: Pandas is a specialized tool which incurs a significant overhead in terms of learning curve and library size. If you are using it for other reasons anyway, there is no reason to avoid it; but to depend on Pandas just to read a piece of text is absurd.